# SSIS package fails to execute Windows 32 bit executable when run from SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

My SSIS package executes 32 bit windows executable from Execute Process task. This runs fine when package is run from BIDS. But when i trigger this package from SQL Agent job it fails with error "The process exit code was "255" while the expected was "0".

I have made sure that "Run As" account for SQL Agent job has full permissions to required paths. I have also tried running SQL Agent job with 32 bit run time. Also on package level I have set Run64BitRuntime to false. But nothing helped.

Comment: When you say run it is a job, is the package deployed to the IS Server or to the file system? Is it deployed remotely or locally? If remotely, when you run the package with DTEXEC what happens? You might also want to look into the free SysInternals utility Process Explorer to see what exactly is being kicked off by the job step.

Comment: It is deployed locally on IS server.

Comment: And when you kick it off using DTEXEC does it run successfully? Just trying to separate whether it's the job agent's problem or not.

Comment: I executed package from command prompt and it worked just fine. But it is failing when run from sql agent. I'm planning to delete existing sql server credential and proxy account for SSIS packages and re-create them to see if it helps.

Comment: I'm able to execute the package from command prompt. But after i save command into batch file and trigger it via scheduled task it fails.

Comment: Have you tried giving your executable a strong name and adding it to the GAC? When running in the server the executables are in the GAC, so any assemblies they require should also be in the GAC.

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old thread, but I am facing the same problem, have you found a solution?